# OMNeT++ simulation speed based on time, not event rate

Tags: omnet++

In normal "Run" simulation mode, is it possible to simulate with a constant time rather than with a constant event rate?

This is a very general question about the OMNeT++ 5.0 simulation engine.

For development and presentation purposes it would be helpful to execute and animate a simulation at a fixed time-based speed (e.g. two minutes per second). The default behavior is to simulate as efficient as possible, resulting in a fixed event/message rate, making visualization hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines in `[General]` section of `omnetpp.ini`:

```
scheduler-class = "omnetpp::cRealTimeScheduler"
realtimescheduler-scaling = 120
```

and then run your simulation in Express mode. The ratio of simulation time to real time is set in the second line. However, you should take into account that in same cases the speed of simulation may be slower than requested (e.g. because of complexity of model).

Comment: Thanks @jerzy-d Sadly it doesn't quite work yet. scaling has it's effect but the Express updates visualization only every ~2 seconds. I have changed the Preferences to lower refresh rates (40ms) but it's not changing anything. I don't think my hardware is the problem as visualization in normal "Run" mode is fluid...

Comment: As Run mode animates all the events and animating an event can take 2-3 second it means that you can simulate only systems where events never happen more often than 2-3 secs. In short, Run mode is definitely NOT usable with the real time scheduler.